# Override footernavigationcomponent with addons

Tags: jsp, sap-commerce-cloud

I have the footernavigationcomponent.jsp and I want to override it with my hybris addon. But I can't find the controller or the impex file where it is referenced.

Do you know where it is referenced?

Comment: This may answer your question : https://www.stackextend.com/hybris/create-a-custom-cms-component-in-hybris/

Answer (score 1):

You can create new component then remove footernavigationcomponent with impex and add your new component to slot.

Answer (score 1):

The impex which includes the footer component is

/merchandiseinitialdata/resources/merchandiseinitialdata/import/sampledata/contentCatalogs/catalogName/cms-content.impex

The controller that is referenced is determined by a complex algorithm. The controller for the footer component is the DefaultCMSComponentController.